# Why is this regex matching also words within a non-capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex

**I have this string (notice the multi-line syntax):**

```
var str = `   Number One: Get this
    Number Two: And this`;
```

**And I want a regex that returns (with `match`):**

```
[str, 'Get this', 'And this']
```

So I tried `str.match(/Number (?:One|Two): (.*)/g);`, **but that's returning:**

```
["Number One: Get this", "Number Two: And this"]
```

---

There can be any whitespace/line-breaks before any `"Number"` word.

Why doesn't it return only what is inside of the capturing group? Am I misundersating something? And how can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the MDN documentation for `String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned.** If there were no matches, the method returns [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).

(emphasis mine).

So, what you want is not possible.

The same page adds:

> - if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead.

so if you're willing to give on using `match`, you can write your own function that repeatedly applies the regex, gets the captured substrings, and builds an array.

---

Or, for your specific case, you could write something like this:

```
var these = str.split(/(?:^|\n)\s*Number (?:One|Two): /);
these[0] = str;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do you know if this is the same with all regex engines? I mean, if this is because of how regex works in general.

Comment: I guess I'm doing this (of course, declaring `arr`): `str.split('\n').forEach( x => arr.push( x.match(/Number (?:One|Two): (.*)/)[1] ) );`, What do you think?

Comment: Ah, didn't see the update, that works too. And @guest271314 's solution works as well, but you explained why it didn't, and that's nice. Thanks. I'm not really interested in the whole string, I just wrote it that way in the question because that's how I thought match always worked with capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
  var str = "   Number One: Get this\
    Number Two: And this";
  // `/\w+\s+\w+(?=\s|$)/g` match one or more alphanumeric characters , 
  // followed by one or more space characters ,
  // followed by one or more alphanumeric characters , 
  // if following space or end of input , set `g` flag 
  // return `res` array `["Get this", "And this"]`  
  var res =  str.match(/\w+\s+\w+(?=\s|$)/g);

  document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice as well, and even nicer with arrow functions!: `var res = str.match(/:\s+\w+\s+\w+/g).map( v => v.replace(": ", "") );`

Answer (score 2):

Replace and store the result in a new string, like this:

```
var str = `   Number One: Get this
Number Two: And this`;
var output = str.replace(/Number (?:One|Two): (.*)/g, "$1");
console.log(output);
```

which outputs:

```
Get this
And this
```

If you want the match array like you requested, you can try this:

```
var getMatch = function(string, split, regex) {
    var match = string.replace(regex, "$1" + split);
    match = match.split(split);
    match = match.reverse();
    match.push(string);
    match = match.reverse();
    match.pop();
    return match;
}

var str = `   Number One: Get this
Number Two: And this`;
var regex = /Number (?:One|Two): (.*)/g;
var match = getMatch(str, "#!SPLIT!#", regex);
console.log(match);
```

which displays the array as desired:

```
[ '   Number One: Get this\n    Number Two: And this',
'   Get this',
'\n    And this' ]
```

Where split (here `#!SPLIT!#`) should be a unique string to split the matches. Note that this only works for single groups. For multi groups add a variable indicating the number of groups and add a for loop constructing `"$1 $2 $3 $4 ..." + split`.

Comment: Thanks! The whole string isn't all that important to me, I just pointed it out because of the way I thought match works. In your first example, one could also do: `output.trim().split('\n');` to get the array, I guess.

Comment: Yes this will also work in this case but I think it'll fail if there is a line without a match.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, it'll also include non-matches in the array.